# Trying to compile character_recognition.cpp from opencv_contrib samples

Tags: opencv, tesseract

I've just installed opencv 3.2 and tesseract module. Now I'm tryng to compile the character_recognition.cpp sample in the opencv_contrib folder. If I use the command `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` it displays

```
-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_reg -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_face -lopencv_plot -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_video -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core
```

But if I try to compile che cpp file

```
g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` character_recognition.cpp -o  character_recognition
```

it says me that `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)` it's not defined and this kind of error for every function of the opencv libraries that is used in the code.

Seems thats I can't link the libraries. Can you help me?

Comment: Edit the #include lines in character_recognition.cpp from `#include "filename.hpp"` to `#include <filename.hpp>` for all the opencv related files.

Comment: i've solved  using  g++ -ggdb character_recognition.cpp -o character_recognition 'pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv '